# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.personals.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I get "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.personals.map is not a function" error.

When I clicked SEARCH  button i get the error. the all other buttons are working. The componentDidMount and searhPersonal methods is same but componentdidmount method brings informations for all personals, the searchPersonal button brings only one personal's informations.

Here is my code.

```
class PersonalSearch extends Component {
 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
            personals: [], 
            identity:''         
    }
    this.addPersonal = this.addPersonal.bind(this);
    this.searchPersonal = this.searchPersonal.bind(this);
    this.editPersonal = this.editPersonal.bind(this);
    this.deletePersonal = this.deletePersonal.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

deletePersonal(identity){
    PersonalService.deletePersonal(identity).then( res => {
        this.setState({personals: this.state.personals.filter(personal => personal.identity !== identity)});
    });
}

viewPersonal(identity){
    this.props.history.push(`/view-personal/${identity}`);
}

editPersonal(identity){
    this.props.history.push(`/add-personal/${identity}`);
}

componentDidMount(){
    PersonalService.getPersonals().then((res) => {
        this.setState({ personals: res.data});
    });
}

searchPersonal(identity){
  alert(identity);
  PersonalService.getPersonalById(identity).then( res => {
    this.setState({ personals: res.data});
    console.log('personal => ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.personals));
});
}

addPersonal(){
    this.props.history.push(`/add-personal/_add`);
}

handleChange = (identity,event) => {
  this.setState({ identity: event.target.value });
}

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        
        <form className='form-container3' >
          <div><TextField id="identity" label="Personel Sorgulama" style={{ width: 300 }} inputProps={{ style: { height: 10 } }} placeholder="Kimlik Numarası Giriniz" onChange={(event) => this.handleChange('identity', event)} InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true, height: 20 }} variant="outlined" /></div>
          <div><Button variant="contained" style={{ width: 130, height: 45, backgroundColor: '#a10505', color: "white" }} size="medium" onClick={ () => this.searchPersonal(this.state.identity)} >SEARCH</Button></div>
        </form>

        <form className='form-container3' >
          <div><Button variant="contained" style={{ width: 150, height: 40 }} size="medium" color="primary" onClick={this.addPersonal}> ADD</Button> </div>
        </form>
        
        <div> 
        <Table  style={{width:1100,marginLeft:400,marginTop:50}}>
       <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> TC KİMLİK NO</th>
        <th> AD SOYAD</th>
        <th> MEDENİ HAL</th>
        <th> DOĞUM YERİ</th>
        <th> DOĞUM TARİHİ</th>
        <th> CEP TELEFONU</th>
        <th> İŞLEMLER</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {
         this.state.personals.map(
            personal => 
                 <tr key = {personal.identity}>
                 <td> {personal.identity}</td>   
                 <td> {personal.name}</td>   
                 <td> {personal.marialStatus}</td>
                 <td> {personal.birthPlace}</td> 
                 <td> {Moment(personal.birthOfDate).add(1,"d").format("DD.MM.YYYY")}</td> 
                 <td> {personal.phoneNumber}</td>  
                 <td >
              <Button variant="contained" style={{ width: 100, height: 30 }} size="medium" color="primary"  onClick={ () => this.viewPersonal(personal.identity)}>GÖRÜNTÜLE</Button>
              <Button variant="contained" style={{ width: 90, height: 30,marginLeft:10 }} size="medium" color="primary"  onClick={ () => this.editPersonal(personal.identity)}>GÜNCELLE</Button>
              <Button variant="contained" style={{ width: 40, height: 30,marginLeft:10 }} size="medium" color="primary" onClick={ () => this.deletePersonal(personal.identity)}>SİL</Button>
                </td>               
            </tr>
        )
    }
</tbody>
</Table>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(PersonalSearch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
searchPersonal(identity){
  alert(identity);
  PersonalService.getPersonalById(identity).then( res => {
    this.setState({ personals: res.data});
    console.log('personal => ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.personals));
});
```

I believe the API returns a single object instead of array of personal object. So after the state updated, your `this.state.personals` is no longer an array, it is an object, then you got the error `this.state.personals.map is not a function`.

Perhaps, the `console.log` output makes you think `this.state.personals` is still an array, but, `setState` runs asynchronously, so what you got from `console.log` here is the previous value of `this.state.personals`.

To get what you want, I think you should change your code inside the function like below:

`this.setState({ personals: res.data})` changed to `this.setState({ personals: [res.data]});`

Answer (score 1):

Service call might be returning null/undefined use null check before the map function

Check on render

`this.state.personals?.map`

Or update in setState to empty array

```
componentDidMount() {
    PersonalService.getPersonals().then((res) => {
        this.setState({
            personals: res.data ?? []  // this might return null 
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.setState({ personals: res.data});
```

Most likely res.data is not an array. Check if you are extracting the right data from server's response.

Answer (score 0):

> the searchPersonal button brings only one personal's informations

That's the issue. If `searchPersonal` returns a single item instead of an array and you execute

```js
this.setState({ personals: res.data});
```

then `this.state.personals` will no longer be an array, causing `this.state.personals.map` to throw an error.

Change your `searchPersonal` to do the following:

```js
searchPersonal(identity){
  alert(identity);
  PersonalService.getPersonalById(identity).then( res => {
    // Put `res.data` in an array, so that `this.state.personals` is an array with a single item
    this.setState({ personals: [res.data]});
    console.log('personal => ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.personals));
});
}
```